# find all word start with specific character followed by digits in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, regex

I want to find all word which start with mc and  followed by all digits only

```
var myString="hi mc1001 hello mc1002 mc1003 mc1004 mc mca"
```

**Require output = [ mc1001,mc1002,mc1003,mc1004]**

My solution:

```
var myRegEx = /(?:^|\s)mc(.*?)(?:\s|$)/g;

function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
    index || (index = 1); // default to the first capturing group
    var matches = [];
    var match;
    console.log("string==",string)
    while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
        console.log("string==",string)
        matches.push(match[index]);
    }
    return matches;
}

var matches = getMatches(myString, myRegEx, 1);
console.log("matches===>",matches)
```

Problem facing:my code is returning all odd possting words only
I am using node js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could search for a word boundary, then the following letters `mc` and some digits followed by another word boundary.

```js
var string = "hi mc1001 hello mc1002 mc1003 mc1004 amc1005 mc mca mc1234a";

console.log(string.match(/\bmc\d+\b/g));
```

Comment: supper thanks, can we get mc followed by at least n digits , value of n we can decide   For example n=2  mc45  mc 32443 accepted  but mc9 not

Comment: you can add a quantifier, like `(/mc\d{4,}/g` for at least 4 digits or more.

Comment: thanks you very much ,simple but powerful solution :)

Comment: Adding word boundaries might be helpful here, to avoid matching `mc1000a` or `amc1000` - if that is an issue at all.

Comment: Without word boundaries this answer is simply wrong, sorry.

Comment: @georg, added some boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this works ?

`\b(mc)\d+\b`

to match all words that start with "mc" and continues by any count of digits after the letter "c".

Comment: Yep it does, but please be a bit more verbose (explain what your regex does, provide a snippet etc).

Comment: sorry, you are right. I should. Next time I'll be more detailed.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use

```
/(mc\d+)/g
```

to match all "mc" followed by digits